# Blazor Passing Data from Parent to Child

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, blazor

I have a razor page which depends on its parent's class and a second child which has its own class and receive data from its parent, my issue is on the second call to the api, the data is not being passed to the second child, the second child is not being render when its parent changes its data but it works on the first render and data is being passed.

Parent.razor

```
@inherits ParentBase;

<FirstChild/>
<SecondChild data="@data"/>
```

FirstChild.razor

```
@inherits ParentBase;

// call its parent method
<span  @onclick='(() => callApi())'/>
```

ParentBase.cs

```
public class ParentBase : ComponentBase
{
   public Data data { get; set; }
   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
       data = await Services.GetData();
   }
   // call from a child
   public void callApi
   {
     data = await Services.GetData();
   }
}
```

SecondChild.razor

```
<Table data="@data"/>
```

SecondChildBase.cs

```
public class SecondChildBase : ComponentBase
{
   [Parameter]
   public Data data { get; set; }

   protected override void OnParametersSet()
   {
       // this is not getting called
       StateHasChanged();
       Console.WriteLine(data);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because `Parent.razor` and `FirstChild.razor` inherits from the same class, it doesn't mean that the data of both classes (`public Data data { get; set; }`) will have the same value when changed.

When you call `callApi` in the `FirstChild`, it will change it's own `data`, if you want to change the parent's `data`, you need to pass a parameter to `FirstChild` which will be a function to call when the `span` is clicked and that will call the `Parent`'s `callApi`.

FirstChild.razor

```
<span @onclick="OnClick">Call Parent function</span>

@code 
{
    // Call this EventCallback when the span is clicked
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

Parent.razor

```
@inherits ParentBase;

@* Passing OnClick Parameter to call callApi*@
<FirstChild OnClick="@callApi" />
<SecondChild data="@data" />
```

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response, the reason I am inheriting the parent class to avoid the use of EventCallback since I have a lot of call to the api from different children and it will be hard to pass EventCallback Specially if the child is nested inside another child.

Comment: For this instance, I have another Child which is inside the Second child which need to make a call to the api and change the data, whats the best approach for that ? thanks

Comment: @AhmedImam If you want multiple child components to access that function and don't want to pass parameter to all of it, you can use `CascadingValue` or create something that looks like a "service". If you want more information on that, please read this [article](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/)

Comment: +1 for cascadingparameter here.. This is the way to go.. I’ll give you the instance of the “parent” in the child component so you can call it directly

Answer (score 4):

I think you can try data-binding instead of CascadingParameter.

Documentation is here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1

particularly on the two topics below:

- Parent-to-child binding with component parameters
- Child-to-parent binding with chained bind

Example: Parent Component

```
<PasswordField @bind-Password="password" />

@code {
    private string password;
}
```

Example: Child Component

```
<input @oninput="OnPasswordChanged" 
       required 
       type="@(showPassword ? "text" : "password")" 
       value="@Password" />

@code {
    private bool showPassword;
    private string password;
    private string validationMessage;

    [Parameter]
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password ?? string.Empty; }
        set
        {
            if (password != value)
            {
                if (value.Contains(' '))
                {
                    validationMessage = "Spaces not allowed!";
                }
                else
                {
                    password = value;
                    validationMessage = string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> PasswordChanged { get; set; }

    private Task OnPasswordChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Password = e.Value.ToString();

        return PasswordChanged.InvokeAsync(Password);
        }

    }
```

Your child component needs to supply a {Password}Changed where {} is your parameter.
This way, when child updates, parents are also updated (as well as all other bind parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Just move the StateHasChanged() to the base after the service call simples....